# Showing a modal popup from iframe?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I am using Bootstrap modal using jquery, Inside modal dialog I have an iframe in which I am opening a page.
In this page user can input some information and it is done using ajax. If user close the modal dialog after submitting, I want to open it again after getting response from ajax call.

How I can perform this condition below  from iframe as the modal is in parent page.

```
if (!$('#myModalCIar', window.parent.document).data('bs.modal').isShown) {
   $('#myModalCIar', window.parent.document).modal('show');
}
```

thanks

Comment: What is your problem now? Are you getting any error ?

Comment: I am getting the object but its not able to recognize .data('bs.modal')